# Codeigniter:$query->free_result() when using active record?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter

after i have finished with my result set from a active record query in a CodeIgniter model, should I use `$query->free_result()` or does ActiveRecord automatically do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP will clean up everything after your script is done. However, if you have lots of queries in, say, a loop, the results will not be cleaned up after each iteration.

So, if you run lots of queries in a loop, you probably will want to free_result() to clear up memory. Otherwise, it's not necessary. See here for details:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: The link no longer works. [The relevant version 3 page is here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-helper-methods)