# How does codeigniter 2 handle classes and objects

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and I was wondering how the system handles all classes and objects. If i have a lot of models, views and controllers does the system release them, when not in use or do i have to do it myself?

an example:

```
class Myclass extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct(){
      parent::_construct();
 }

 public function some_function(){
    $this->load->view("some_view");
 }
```

}

I also got a question on the database part. Does CodeIgniter save query results, or do I have to release every query, I don't want to be saved with `$query->free_result()` ?

Comment: you're not required to release anything. consider the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775111/codeigniterquery-free-result-when-using-active-record

Answer (score 1):

Active records does it automatically.
for more details please check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

And just to inform you that codeigniter has its own fantastic documentation for his core library. So, if you follow their guidlines then you will be codeigniter geek.